# Are there reinforcement learning algorithms that ensure convergence for continuous state space problems?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, convergence

The Q-learning does not guarantee convergence for continuous state space problems ([Why doesn't Q-learning converge when using function approximation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/11679/why-doesnt-q-learning-converge-when-using-function-approximation)). In that case, is there an algorithm which can guarantee convergence?

I am looking at model-based RL specifically iLQR but all the solutions I find are for the continuous action space problem.