# Does TD(0) prediction require Robbins-Monro conditions to converge to the value function?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, math, proofs, convergence, temporal-difference-methods

Does the learning rate parameter $\alpha$ require the Robbins-Monro conditions below for the TD(0) algorithm to converge to the true value function of a policy?

$$\sum \alpha_t =\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \sum \alpha^{2}_t <\infty$$

Comment: This question was also asked at [https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/451115/82135](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/451115/82135).

Answer (score 1):

The paper [Convergence of Q-learning: A Simple Proof](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~mtjspaan/readingGroup/ProofQlearning.pdf) (by Francisco S. Melo) shows (theorem 1) that Q-learning, a TD(0) algorithm, converges with probability 1 to the optimal Q-function as long as the Robbins-Monro conditions, for all combinations of states and actions, are satisfied. In other words, the Robbins-Monro conditions are [sufficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency) for Q-learning to converge to the optimal Q-function in the case of a finite MDP. The proof of theorem 1 uses another theorem from [stochastic approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation) (theorem 2).

You are interested in the [prediction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/340462/82135) problem, that is, the problem of predicting the expected return (i.e. a value function) from a fixed policy. However, Q-learning is *also* a control algorithm, given that it can find the optimal policy from the corresponding learned Q-function.

See also the question [Why doesn't Q-learning converge when using function approximation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444).

Comment: Thanks for that, I was wondering is it true that TD(0) converges to the value function in Expected value when $\alpha$ is constant? Is there a condition that $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Comment: @KaneM Right now, I am not aware of this result. Please, ask another question on the site because may someone else can answer your question.

Comment: The result is in Sutton's [Learning to Predict by the Methods of Temporal Differences](http://incompleteideas.net/papers/dayan-92.pdf) , on page 24 of this version. I think I understand the result now. It is saying that there is some range of  alphas $\alpha \in (0,t)$ such that TD(0) converges to the value function in expected value.