# Why is it hard to prove the convergence of the deep Q-learning algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn, convergence, function-approximation

Why is it hard to prove the convergence of the DQN algorithm? We know that the tabular Q-learning algorithm converges to the optimal Q-values, and with a linear approximator convergence is proved.

The main difference of DQN compared to Q-Learning with linear approximator is using DNN, the experience replay memory, and the target network. Which of these components causes the issue and why?

Comment: See [Why doesn't Q-learning converge when using function approximation?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I carefully read the post, it does not actually answer my question.