# How can deep Q-learning converge if the targets may not be correct?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, dqn, deep-rl, convergence

In deep Q-learning, $Q(s, a)$ and $Q'(s, a)$ are predicted or estimated by the neural network itself. In supervised learning, the target value is a true unbiased value. However, this isn't the case in reinforcement learning. So, how can we be sure that deep Q-learning converges? How do we know that the target Q values are accurate?

Comment: See https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/21053/2444 and https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11679/2444.